# Async requests calling after stream has ended

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, request

I'm having issues with nodeJS streaming. The issue I have is in one of my streams I send a request, using the request module (which is asynchronous) and by the time the request gets a response, the whole stream finishes.

Here is the code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
var locations = [];
var urls = [];
var MAP_QUEST_KEY = 'mykey';
var MAP_QUEST_URL = 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=' + MAP_QUEST_KEY + '&inFormat=json&json=';
var CSV_FILE_NAME = 'smaller_stores.csv';
var inFile = path.join(__dirname, 'input', CSV_FILE_NAME);
var outFile = path.join(__dirname, 'output', CSV_FILE_NAME);
// create a location object
var createLocationJSONStream = function (data) {
    var location = {
        street: data.street_no + ' ' + data.street_name,
        city: data.city_name,
        state: data.state_id
    };
    var url = MAP_QUEST_URL + JSON.stringify(location);
    // this request finishes after stream
    request({
        url: 'url',
        method: 'GET',
        json: location
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            data.lat = body.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lat;
            data.lng = body.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lng;
        }
        return data;
    });
};
var readFileStream = fs.createReadStream(inFile);
var writeFileStream = fs.createWriteStream(outFile);
var parseCsvStream = csv.parse({
    trim: true,
    headers: true,
    objectMode: false
});
var deserializeJSONStream = JSONStream.parse();
var streamingEvent = readFileStream.pipe(parseCsvStream).transform(createLocationJSONStream).pipe(deserializeJSONStream);
// eventually want to write out to csv
//.pipe(csv.createWriteStream({headers: true}))
//.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(outFile, {encoding: 'utf8'}));
streamingEvent.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
streamingEvent.on('end', function () {
    console.log('end');
});
```

Here is the output:

```
end
200
application/json; charset=utf-8
200
application/json; charset=utf-8
200
application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Here is the example csv:

```
 region_id    region_name     street_no   street_name                sitetype_id      country_name    timezone_no     geocode_id      city_name               state_id    zip_code      county_name
3             West  350         ORCHARD AVE              N              USA 4   954824536      UKIAH                      CA            95482-4536    MENDOCINO
1             South 1000           4TH AVE                   N              USA 7   333041903      FORT LAUDERDALE          FL          33304-1903    BROWARD
0             Northeast 1370           HURFVILLE RD                N                USA 7   80963818       DEPTFORD                NJ           08096-3818    GLOUCESTER
```

I know I am handling the streams wrong, but dont know what is the easiest way to fix it? Pipe to the request?

Comment: Why do you want the request to finish before the stream?

Comment: I want to augment the csv file with the lat / long info

Answer (score 1):

If you want the async `request()` operation to finish before you start your stream code, then you need to put the stream code INSIDE the completion callback for your request.  That way, you don't start your stream code until after you've received the data from your `request()` operation.

In addition, you can't return a value form an async operation like you were trying to do `return data;`.  Returning data from a callback just goes back into the callback infrastructure.  The outer function has long since already returned and subsequent lines of code after the outer function have already been executed.  Instead, you must consume the result INSIDE the callback itself or make a function call from within that callback and pass the data to that other function.

I don't follow exactly what you're trying to do with the streams, but here's where they would go if you want to make sure the `request()` operation is done before you do your streams:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
var locations = [];
var urls = [];
var MAP_QUEST_KEY = 'mykey';
var MAP_QUEST_URL = 'http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=' + MAP_QUEST_KEY + '&inFormat=json&json=';
var CSV_FILE_NAME = 'smaller_stores.csv';
var inFile = path.join(__dirname, 'input', CSV_FILE_NAME);
var outFile = path.join(__dirname, 'output', CSV_FILE_NAME);
// create a location object
var createLocationJSONStream = function (data) {
    var location = {
        street: data.street_no + ' ' + data.street_name,
        city: data.city_name,
        state: data.state_id
    };
    var url = MAP_QUEST_URL + JSON.stringify(location);
    // this request finishes after stream
    request({
        url: 'url',
        method: 'GET',
        json: location
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            // get the latLng position so we can use it in our streaming
            var position = body.results[0].locations[0].latLng;

            var readFileStream = fs.createReadStream(inFile);
            var writeFileStream = fs.createWriteStream(outFile);
            var parseCsvStream = csv.parse({
                trim: true,
                headers: true,
                objectMode: false
            });
            var deserializeJSONStream = JSONStream.parse();
            var streamingEvent = readFileStream.pipe(parseCsvStream).transform(createLocationJSONStream).pipe(deserializeJSONStream);
            // eventually want to write out to csv
            //.pipe(csv.createWriteStream({headers: true}))
            //.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(outFile, {encoding: 'utf8'}));
            streamingEvent.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            });
            streamingEvent.on('end', function () {
                console.log('end');
            });            
        }
    });
};
```

The latLng coordinates are now available in the `position` variable anywhere in your streaming code and your streaming operation does not start until that data is ready.

FYI, I've found that any code involving multiple async operations is ultimately easier to write, understand and do robust error handling if you use promises instead of plain callbacks.  This requires learning how promises work and often involves "promisifying" some operations (turning regular async operations into operations that return a promise).  So, for the longer term, I'd suggest you start learning promises.  I use the Bluebird promise library for my node.js development as it has lots of helpful features.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm using the fast-csv library which allows returns of transforms: https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv. To be clear I'm taking one csv file, and trying to add lat/longs to it based on the address. The input and output csv will contain mostly the same data, but with the response from the request (lat/long data)

Comment: @oliveromahony - I was just confused because no code you included in your question actually uses the lat/long value that you obtained.  Did this answer help you figure out how you should solve your problem?

Comment: no, the lat/long is in the request callback:            data.lat = body.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lat;
            data.lng = body.results[0].locations[0].latLng.lng;

Comment: @oliveromahony - what are you still confused by?  The way I've modified your code the lat long data is now available in all your streaming code in the `position` variable.